# How can I implement Facebook Audience Network notifications in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-audience-network

I am successfully loading ads, but I can't get the notifications to fire.

For example;

```
class ViewController : UIViewController , FBAdViewDelegate {
    ...
    func adViewDidLoad(adView: FBAdView) {
        print("ad loaded"); // never called, although ad displays
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not assigning the delegate;

```
self.fanView = FBAdView(placementID:PLACEMENT_ID, 
    adSize:kFBAdSizeHeight50Banner, rootViewController:self);
self.fanView.delegate = self; // needed this
```